# What does it mean exit (0) and exit (1)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code look like this , it's not clear to me exit (0) and exit (other num).
 I give myself sometime but i didn't clear myself enough

```
from sys import exit
class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured"
        exit(1)
```

Comment: It's the value returned by the program to the system. Usually, a value of 0 means "properly exited", and other values indicate a failure.

Comment: Hellow evert,  you means it gives the error massage, right?

Answer (score 1):

`exit(0)` means a clean exit without an error

`exit(1)` means there was an error and that is the reason for the exit